# what does theSize/2 means percolateDown(i) function?

Tags: c++, heap

What does theSize/2 means in the following code,
Is this somehow  related with Insertion O(LogN)?

```
template <class Comparable>
void BinaryHeap<Comparable>::buildHeap( )
{
    for( int i = theSize / 2; i > 0; i-- )
        percolateDown( i );
}
```

For this percolateDown function

```
template <class Comparable>
void BinaryHeap<Comparable>::percolateDown( int hole )
{
  int child;
  Comparable tmp = array[ hole ];

  for( ; hole * 2 <= theSize; hole = child )
  {
    child = hole * 2;
    if( child != theSize && array[child + 1] < array[child])
       child++;
    if( array[ child ] < tmp )
       array[ hole ] = array[ child ];
    else
       break;
  }
  array[ hole ] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: There is no `size/2`.  Are you asking what `theSize / 2` means?

Comment: To me it means "start in the middle".

Comment: Unless theSize is an object with a `/` operator overload that does something unusual, this should be division by 2.

Comment: Yes NathanOliver I mean theSize/2. In other words,the size of the list of numbers to be inserted into the binary Heap.

Answer (score 2):

A very common representation of a heap is to map it to an array. In this representation, for any node stored at `a[n]` its children are at `a[n*2]` and `a[n*2+1]`. The root node is at `a[1]`.

Given that, dividing the index by two (and discarding any remainder) is simply how you get from the index of a node to the index of its parent.

In the case of `percolateDown` the idea is to start with the nodes one level above the leaves of the heap.

Try searching for "heap in array" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It turned out that theSize/2 leads us to the last subtree of unsorted , Binary Heap where we start to percolateDown(i)(sorting function).

Then we move to the (i-1)th subtree and percolateDown() that one. And so on Until the Binary Heap Tree is sorted either Max or Min.

It is clarified in this video from time 2:42  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsNQuCa_-PU)